# Get values block by block in same file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, perl, ksh

I have a file say "SAMPLE.txt" with following content,

```
P1
10,9:6/123456
P2
blah blah
P1
10,9:5/98765
P2
blah
blah
P1
blah blah
P2
```

I want a output file say "RESULT.txt" as,

```
Value1:123456
Value2:98765
Value3:NULL
```

I need to first fetch content between P1 & P2 part then I want to find value of 10,9*/ which I want to save to another value. Incase some P1--P2 block doesn't contain this value I want to save it as "NULL".

How can I code the above in shell/awk ?

I am very new to scripting.

Answer (score 2):

This works and is fully portable:

```
sed '\|^P1.*|!d;s||Value:|
     :n
     N;\|\nP2|!bn
     s|:.*\n10,9[^/]*/|:|
     s|\n.*||;s|:$|:NULL|'
```

The flow works like this:

1. First it addresses a line `^`beginning with `P1`
2. If the current line `!`doesn't match it `d`eletes it.
3. If it does, it replaces `P1` with `Value:`
4. It then sets the `:n`ext label and pulls in the `N`ext line.
5. If `\nP2` is `!`not then found it `b`ranches back to the `:n`ext label and tries again repeatedly until it occurs.
6. It then deletes any occurrence of `:.*\n10,9` up to the first occurring `/` character.
7. It deletes the first `\n`ewline available and all following characters.
8. If the last character is the `:`colon following `Value` it inserts the string `NULL`.

Steps 6 and 7 are what makes it work - in 6 it deletes the `\n`ewline preceding your desired number string, but if that isn't there then the next `\n`ewline will be the one immediately following `Value:` so *everything* goes in step 7.

Here it is in action:

```
sed '\|^P1.*|!d;s||Value:|
     :n
     N;\|\nP2|!bn
     s|:.*\n10,9[^/]*/|:|
     s|\n.*||;s|:$|:NULL|' <<\DATA
P1
10,9:6/123456
P2
blah blah
P1
10,9:5/98765
P2
blah
blah
P1
blah blah
P2
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Value:123456
Value:98765
Value:NULL
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks for very much for the edit - I didn't know labels had to be separated in that way. Which leaves me wondering - is it only that they can't precede other statements on the line but can be preceded themselves or is it neither? I'm not going to alter it - it's cleaner looking this way anyway - but would it work *POSIXly* if it were instead: `...s||Value|;:n`?

Comment: `cmd;:n` is OK. label names can have any character including `;` (possibly not trailing blanks). In that regard GNU `sed` is not POSIX compliant (though nobody in their right mind would use labels such as `n;N;...`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I was actually just looking at it. I wonder why GNU `sed` discriminates between the way it handles `:`label and  `r`,`a`,`i`,`w` - it obeys the spec in all of the latter cases but bends the rules for the former though it's the same rule for all. Probably it's what you say - the semi-colon makes the difference. As for being in my right mind - I don't think any such claim would stand up under scrutiny, so I don't make it... Anyway, thanks again, as always. Someday you're gonna let me know where you *keep* all of that info...

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` (slurps the whole file in memory though):

```
 perl -0777 -ne 'while (/P1\n(.*?)\nP2/gs) {
   printf "Value%d:%s\n", ++$n, $1 =~ /^10,9.*\// ? $'\'': "NULL"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -F'/' -alne '
    if (/P1/../P2/ and $_ !~ /^P/) {
        print "Value@{[++$i]}:",$F[1]?$F[1]:"NULL";
    }
' file
Value1:123456
Value2:98765
Value3:Null
```

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F'/' '/P2/{f=0};/P1/{f=1;next};f{print "Value"++i":"($2?$2:"Null")}' file
Value1:123456
Value2:98765
Value3:Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '$0=="P1" {f=1} $0=="P2" {f=0}f' file | paste - - | \
    awk -F"\t" '$2~/[0-9]/ {split ($2,a,"/"); \
    print "Value"NR":"a[2]} $2!~/[0-9]/ {print "Value"NR":NULL"}'
Value1:123456
Value2:98765
Value3:NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. This is the piece of code that finally solved my problem.

```
nawk -v fname="${filename}" -F '/|:' '

    function isnum(x){return(x==x+0)}

    /P1/,/P3/{
            # Found start increment i reset variables go to next line
            if(/P1/){
                   ++i 
                   fid ="" 
                   count++
                   next
                }

            # Found end validate variable and print go to next line
            if(/P3/){
                printf "%s|",count
                printf "%s|",isnum(fid)?fid:"NULL"
                  next 
                }
            if(!fid && /36,59:*/)
                {
                    fid = $NF
                }
        ' ${filename} >>output.txt
```

But now I am having another issue for which I have created a separate thread.

Here is the link if you guys can help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277167/finding-and-replacing-text-inside-awk-block?noredirect=1#comment37509363_24277167